# WEBPACK 4 SplitChunksPlugin doesntsplit

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

i set

```

```
optimization:{
splitChunks: 
    'my-bundle1':{
          chunks:"async",
test: (module)=>{
return  /my-bundle1/.test(module.resource)
},
name:"my-bundle1",
enforce:true,
reuseExistingChunk:true

}}
```

```

however, the source of the files with paths containing my-bundle1 does NOT appear in my-bundle1.bundle.js. rather they appear in common.js

PS: in webpack 3 I used to create these bundles by a list of commonsChunkPlugins:

`new CommonsChunkPlugin({
"minChunks":function(module,count) {
return module.resource & /my-bundle1//.test(module.resource) && count>=2; 
},
"async":"mybundle1-1.0.0"
}),
...`

Comment: The value of splitChunks property will be enclosed inside {}

Comment: @kryptokinght  that is pseudo JSON code

Answer (score 0):

answer was to elevate priority. once i added priority:100 it worked